# Robot Framework --skip option does not show up the skipped test case in robot report

Tags: robotframework

I am executing the robot command with --skip for specific test case skipped in the commandline. But the skipped test case is not listed in the report. Instead --skip behaves like --exclude

```
robot --skip test_case_2 -i test_case_1 ./robot_test
```

While executing Total number of test cases display as one. And neither in the robot log.html, the skipped test case is displayed.